# Next 13.4 Error: NEXT_REDIRECT in API routes

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

My `/app/api/auth/route.ts` file:

```js
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
    
export async function GET(req: Request) {
  try {
    redirect('/dashboard');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    redirect('/');
  }
}
```

I realized that when I do redirect in a try catch, I get the error :

```
Error: NEXT_REDIRECT
        at getRedirectError (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect.js:40:19)
        at redirect (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect.js:46:11)
        at GET (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./app/api/auth/route.ts:23:66)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
        at async eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:244:37) {
      digest: 'NEXT_REDIRECT;replace;/dashboard'
    }
```

When I get get rid of the try catch everything works fine:

```js
export async function GET(req: Request) {
  redirect('/dashboard')
}
```

This works as expected. I need try and catch because this is an auth route and I need some error handling because the request could fail, I have left out the auth functionalities because I realized that this happens just on a simple try and catch.

Or if Next 13 has another way of error handling in `/api` routes please let me know.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I'm running into the same issue except it doesn't work outside the try catch either... Mine is in a dynamic route [id] not sure if that's causing it

Comment: I also ran into the same issue. I ended up using `appRouter`, instead. I read in the documentation that redirect returns an an NEXT_REDIRECT https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect#example, but i don't understand why and I don't understand how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: I got this while using it in a Promise resolution's `then` callback. I realized this is a client component so I changed to `useRouter` and `router.push` instead.

Comment: why do they make a method `redirect` you cannot call without getting an error? Redirecting is just about the most basic thing you can do in a web app. And they make this complicated too? We should go back to vanilla JS it seems

Answer (score 30):

At the moment, the workaround I found is to not use:

```
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
```

But to use instead:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
const router = useRouter()
router.push("/")
```

Comment: Be aware that these are different methods, each with its trade-offs. "useRouter" operates as a frontend utility, whereas "redirect" is applicable on the server side. Switching between these approaches may result in your page relying more on client components and JavaScript for full functionality. In my view, following @Rugile Venskute's suggestion seems to be the most suitable solution for now.

Comment: You can't use a hook in server code. This assumes the component is a client component.

Comment: This is only for client components, the question clearly states that the redirect has to be performed in an API route.

Answer (score 17):

It's easy to fix it. Currently, there is a bug in `try-catch` block with Next redirect. But you don't need to change anything. You just need to transfer `try-catch` block to different function. I can give you an example of my code:

```js
"use server";
import LoginSchema from "@/Schemas/LoginSchema";
import PocketBase from "pocketbase";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

const analyze = async (data) => {
  const pb = new PocketBase("http://127.0.0.1:8090");
  try {
    const authData = await pb
      .collection("UserTable")
      .authWithPassword(await data.Email, await data.Password);
    if (authData) {
      return authData;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    error;
  }
};

export async function LoginAction(data) {
  const result = await LoginSchema.isValid(await data);
  if (result === true) {
    const result = await analyze(data);
    if (result) {
      return redirect("/");
    } else {
      return "failed";
    }
  } else {
    return "failed";
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to return it. As per docs, redirect does not require you to use return redirect() as it uses the TypeScript never type.

Answer (score 12):

When using `redirect` in a server component you should move it to the `finally` block. Here is how:

```js
export default async function Page() {
    let redirectPath: string | null = null

    try {
        //Rest of the code
        redirectPath = `/dashboard`
    } catch (error) {
        //Rest of the code
        redirectPath = `/`
    } finally {
        //Clear resources
        if (redirectPath)
            redirect(redirectPath)
    }

    return <>{/*Rest of JSX*/}</>
}
```

From the [redirect documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/redirecting#redirect-function):

> `redirect` internally throws an error so it should be called outside of `try/catch` blocks.

In `api routes` you should use the `NextResponse` from `next/server`. Here is how

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function GET(request: NextRequest) {
    try {
        //Code
        return NextResponse.redirect(`<an absolute url>`)
    } catch {
        //Error handling code
        return NextResponse.redirect(`<an absolute url>`)
    } finally {
        //Clear resources
        //No redirect here
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this. i got sick try to fix this issue over few days, because the example from the video is different! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDpZfOQBMaU 4:12 secs. they sample is different

Comment: This was the only solution posted here that worked for me (without having to drastically change my code). Thank you!

Comment: This is a great solution! Confirmed working on Next14

Comment: This is weird, but worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

This is because internally, redirect() is throwing an Error.
See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/src/client/components/redirect.ts#L16-L41C2

Comment: note that the line number in the fragment you linked may change in the future. You may want to anchor to a specific git tag instead of the canary branch.

Comment: Wow, what an awful thing. Good find, sort of buried in the docs here (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect#example), but I never would have looked there, since its such odd behavior, but its the hack they need if streaming.

Comment: This is actually _kinda_ the right answer. Do not catch `redirect` instead, put it after the catch block.

Comment: I've read the above code, nowhere i can see where exactly it redirects to the given url?

Answer (score 5):

use
return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/home', request.url))

in next 13+ app dir server side

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead.

```js
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

export async function GET(req: Request) {
  try {
    // Other logic
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    redirect('/');
  }

  redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

Internally, `redirect` throws an error as mentioned [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect#example). Hence, you should not catch it nor return it.

Answer (score 1):

The error that I got was `Uncaught (in promise) Error: NEXT_REDIRECT`

And I'm not sure if this is a bug... Because the method needs context info that is available inside "react render time!".

So this will work if you create a reference to use it later.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

function reactFunctionComponent() {
  const router = useRouter()
  runWithPromise().then( () => router.push("/") )
  ...
}
```

[More info](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42556#issuecomment-1454194139)

Answer (score 1):

this is `redirect` function:

```
function redirect(url, type) {
    if (type === void 0) type = "replace";
    throw getRedirectError(url, type, false);
}
```

this is `getRedirectError()`

```
function getRedirectError(url, type, permanent) {
    if (permanent === void 0) permanent = false;
    const error = new Error(REDIRECT_ERROR_CODE);
    error.digest = REDIRECT_ERROR_CODE + ";" + type + ";" + url + ";" + permanent;
    const requestStore = _requestasyncstorageexternal.requestAsyncStorage.getStore();
    if (requestStore) {
        error.mutableCookies = requestStore.mutableCookies;
    }
    return error;
}
```

Finally this is `REDIRECT_ERROR_CODE` IN `getRedirectError`:

```
const REDIRECT_ERROR_CODE = "NEXT_REDIRECT";
```

As you see, `redirect()` throws an error and next.js watches for this error and redirects the user. so when you put `redirect` inside a `try/catch` block, `catch` block catches this error. that is why you see the error. solution is put the `redirect` outside `try/catch` block

this feature is similar in sveltekit. in sveltekit we explicitly throw the `redirect`. maybe `next.js` should be more explicit. This can make the code more understandable to other programmers, and it can also make it easier to debug and maintain.  in `sveltekit`:

```
export const GET: RequestHandler = () => {
    throw redirect(307,`URL`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use server actions with client-side, check this [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect#client-component) in nextjs doc

```
 export async function appRedirect(route: string) {
      redirect(route)
    }

    // use it with async-await
    await appRedirect()
```

Answer (score 1):

the redirect() is never supposed to be used in try catch blocks.
Here is a screenshot from the official docs:
[screenshot of nextjs documentation about redirect()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RG89.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to copy/paste or type the actual text directly into the post (for code, use a code block). [Text in images can pose issues for a number of people (mobile users, people using screen readers,...).](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I used a `try...catch` statement. Rewrote my code in a way that didn't need a `try...catch` statement and it now works fine. This doesn't necessarily happen to API route files only, could happen in a react component where redirect is called inside a try catch.

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel De León said the function needs to run in a react component. A clean workaround is to return the redirect call. ex:

```
function redirectUser(user) {
  if(user.isAdmin) {
    return redirect('/dashboard');
  } else {
    return redirect('401');
  }
}

export default async function ServerComponent(user){
  await redirectUser(user);
}
```

Comment: `redirect` doesn't return a Promise, so `async/await` is unnecessary here. Also, very easy to simplify this to `redirect(user.isAdmin ? '/dashboard' : '401')`.

Comment: @ADTC You are correct; it doesn't return a promise. and it can be simplified But this is ripped from one of my projects. I was trying to show a real-world example where you might have some logic in the function to check the user credentials. And this logic would most likely be needing async/await. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: You can make it clearer by writing on one line: `await someAsyncFunction();` and next line: `redirectUser(user);` :)

Answer (score 0):

Just return the response then redirect in a file that does not have a try catch block.So this could be the client or server component where the response goes

Answer (score 0):

If anyone faced this issue, use `isRedirectError()` function which returns true if the error is generated by `redirect()`.

```js
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

export async function GET(req: Request) {
  try {
    redirect('/dashboard');
  } catch (error) {
    // Do nothing if the error is generated by the redirect()
    if (!isRedirectError(error)) {
      console.log(error);
      redirect('/');
    }
  }
}
```