# Redirecting to Origin URL with Next.js Route Not Working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, supabase, next.js13

I'm currently working on a Next.js application where I have a layout component inside the app directory. Within that component, I have a navbar client component. I'm attempting to implement a logout feature, where clicking a button on the navbar should redirect the user to the origin page using a server-side route. However, it isn't working as expected.

When I click the logout button, the server logs confirm that the route is being called, and I'm getting a "Status: 200 OK" response, but the redirect isn't happening.

Here's the code snippet for the route:

```js
import { createRouteHandlerClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const requestUrl = new URL(request.url);
  const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient({ cookies });

  await supabase.auth.signOut();
  console.log("Salir sesion ruta llamada");

  // Log the origin to the console
  console.log("Origin URL:", requestUrl.origin);

  return NextResponse.redirect(`${requestUrl.origin}/`, {
    // a 301 status is required to redirect from a POST to a GET route
    status: 301,
  });
}
```

I have already verified the origin URL, ensured the correct HTTP method, and checked for other common issues, but I'm still encountering this problem.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or does anyone have suggestions on what might be going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want the redirect to happen in frontend, or backend? Because from your code, you just added a redirect in api, which will have no impact in frontend.

Comment: So that means when someone call `/api/a` and you add a redirect to `api/b` inside `a`, they will get response from `api/b` (assuming set to follow redirects). On frontend side, no impact.

Comment: @RobinThomas Hi Robin,

Thank you for your quick reply! Your explanation makes sense.

I'm looking to change the page on the frontend, so I believe, based on your guidance, that I should use the `useRouter` hook from Next.js to handle the redirect. By utilizing this hook, I can make a request to my logout endpoint and then use `router.push('/')` to redirect the user to the desired page upon a successful response.

Does that look like the correct approach to you? Any further suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have confused between redirects on browser vs server.

When you add a redirect to an API like,

```
return NextResponse.redirect(`api/b`, {
  status: 301,
});
```

What that means is, if try to `fetch` a response from `api/a`, it shall redirect and get the response from `api/b` (assuming follow-redirects option is set).

What you actually want is a redirect on the browser side.

---

You can accomplish this in Next.js using (assuming you are using `app` router):

```
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default async function Profile({ shouldRedirect }) {
  if (shouldRedirect) {
    redirect('/')
  }
 
  // ...
}
```

Refer to https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect for more details.

Comment: Hi Robin, your tips on Next.js browser vs server redirects really helped me out. I ran into an "Error: NEXT_REDIRECT" with `NextResponse.redirect`, but using `router.push("/")` fixed it just like that. Your idea to use the `useRouter` hook was spot-on. If anyone else is stuck on this, I found more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76191324/next-13-4-error-next-redirect-in-api-routes). Thanks a bunch, Robin!