# Nextjs API always returns html format not the expected json format

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am trying to sign out user, I'm using next-auth@beta(not sure whether this would help to fix my issue, but I just include this info here.)

this is my dashboard sidebar component `src\components\ap-sidebar.tsx`

```
import { Button, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styles from './ap-sidebar.module.css';
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export function Sidebar({ activeTab, setActiveTab }: { activeTab: string, setActiveTab: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>}) {
    const router = useRouter();

    const handleSelect = (selectedTab: string | null, event: React.SyntheticEvent<unknown>) => {
        if (selectedTab) {
            setActiveTab(selectedTab);
        }
    };

    const handleSignOut = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/signout', { method: 'POST' });
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          console.error("sign out error : " + response.status);
          return;
        }

        const a = await response.json(); // error happens on this  line.
        console.log(a.message);

        router.push('/');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    return (
    <Nav variant="pills" className={styles.sidebar} activeKey={activeTab} onSelect={handleSelect}>
      <Nav.Item className={styles.navItem}>
        <Nav.Link eventKey="artworks">
            <i className="bi bi-images"></i> &nbsp;
            Artworks
        </Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>

      <Nav.Item className={styles.navItem}>
        <Nav.Link eventKey="users">
            <i className="bi bi-people"></i> &nbsp;
            Users
        </Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>

      <div className={styles.spaceHolder}></div>
      
      <Nav.Item className={styles.navItem}>
        <Button variant="outline-danger" onClick={handleSignOut}>
            <i className="bi bi-power"></i> Sign Out
        </Button>
      </Nav.Item>
    </Nav>
  );
}

export function ArtworkManager() {
  return <div style={{width: "100%"}}>Artwork Manager</div>;
}

export function UserManager() {
  return <div style={{width: "100%"}}>User Manager</div>;
}
```

The `src/app/api/signout/route.ts`

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { signOut } from '../../../../auth'; 

// export async function POST(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
export async function POST(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  await signOut();
  return res.json({ message: 'Signed out' });
  // return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Signed out' });
  // return res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Signed out', status: 200 }));
  // return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Signed out', status: 200 }), {
  //   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  // });
}
```

As you can see that I have searched many posts and tried so many different ways(commented code), but the error is so stubborn, always happens on this line of code:

`const a = await response.json();`

Error message:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Any help is appreciated.

---

**Update 1**

I now use NextResponse to return the json success message within try/catch blocks.
But it goes straight to the catch block. Not sure why

[image]

**Update 2**

I am using

> "next": "^14.0.4",

> "next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.4"

My original intent was to do something like:

```
import { signOut } from '../../auth';
const handleSignOut = async () => {
  "use server"
  try {
    await signOut({ redirectTo: '/' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

And here is the `auth.ts`

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authConfig } from './auth.config';
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { z } from 'zod';
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

 
async function getUser(email: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
      .....
}
 
export const { auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
    ...authConfig,
    providers: [
      Credentials({
        async authorize(credentials) {

          const parsedCredentials = z
            .object({ email: z.string().email(), password: z.string().min(6) })
            .safeParse(credentials);
   
          if (parsedCredentials.success) {
            const { email, password } = parsedCredentials.data;
            const user = await getUser(email);
            if (!user) return null;
            const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.passwordhash);

            if (passwordsMatch) return user;
          }
   
          console.log('Invalid credentials');
          return null;
        },
      }),
    ],
  });
```

But when I did this, I got the following error.

[image]

---

**Update 3**

when using signOut() in server side inside `actions.ts` as @AdamBeleko mentioned, it will throw exception as designed. so if I really want to use try/catch block, then this is how I did it.

`actions.ts`

```
export async function handleSignOutServer(): Promise<boolean> {
  try {
    await signOut();
    return true;
  } catch (error) { 
    if ((error as Error).message === 'NEXT_REDIRECT') return true;
    console.error('An unexpected error happened during sign out:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

In my UI component:

> <Button variant="outline-danger" onClick={() => handleSignOut()}>
> .............

```
const handleSignOut = async () => {
  try {
    const success = await handleSignOutServer();
    if (success === true)
    {
      router.push('/');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

But this seems over complicated. So in order to reduce the overhead complexity, I did this:

`actions.ts`

```
export async function handleSignOutServer() {
  await signOut();
}
```

In UI component:

```
<Button variant="outline-danger" onClick={() => handleSignOutServer()}>
```

In this way, there is no overhead code and it looks nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might just be with your API route. Responses in NextJS 13 are resolved from the NextResponse module and not from the API function parameter as in previous versions. To be more specific, you have to import and use the `NextResponse` module:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { signOut } from '../../../../auth'; 

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    await signOut();
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Signed out' }, {
        status: 200,
    });
  } catch {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' }, {
      status: 500,
    });
  }
}
```

It is also important to make sure that the `signout` function is not a client-side function (is probably an API request) and can therefore run in server-side code.

**Update:**
The error you're getting is related to the automatic redirect by the auth's signout function. See: [Next 13.4 Error: NEXT_REDIRECT in API routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76191324/next-13-4-error-next-redirect-in-api-routes)

To go through this issue, try setting the redirect option to false:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { signOut } from '../../../../auth'; 

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    // set redirect to false
    await signOut({ redirect: false });
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Signed out' }, {
        status: 200,
    });
  } catch {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' }, {
      status: 500,
    });
  }
}
```

Alternatively, use the signout function directly in your client 'handleSignOut' function as per the documentation and set the redirectTo option with the path you want to redirect to:

```
const handleSignOut = async () => {
      "use server"
      try {
        await signOut({ redirectTo: '/' });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
```

See: https://authjs.dev/reference/nextjs#signout

**Update 2**
To use server function in the client component, create a file which will contain server functions only:

```
// app/actions.js
'use server'

import { signOut } from './path/to/auth';
 
export async function handleSignout() {
  try {
    await signOut({ redirect: false });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Later, import the component inside your client component:

```
import { handleSignout } from '@/app/actions'
```

You can now use the function in your code. Make sure to remove the handleSignout callback in your client component code.

See: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations#client-components

Comment: Thanks Adam, I updated my code accordingly and got it straight landed in the catch block. I uploaded new code and error screenshot.

Comment: @Franva I have updated the answer with a workaround

Comment: Hi @Adam, I hope you had a great Xmas and thank you for your update. The alternative approach is my preference actually. I have tried your suggestion and got an error. Please see my **update 2**.

Comment: Hi @Franva, I updated the answer to import the server function instead since the component contains client-side code. Please see **Update 2**

Comment: Hi @adam, I have updated my code according to your suggestion, but it has a little glitch, but I managed to fixed it. Then I simplified the code. I'm not sure it is the proper way to do it. Please see my **Update 3**.

Comment: @Franva you did it well. Does it work now?

Comment: You're welcome @Franva I updated my **Update 2** to disable redirecting which causes the 'NEXT_REDIRECT' error. Happy for you to finally get it working!

Comment: Hi Adam, since the design of signOut() uses exception to do redirect, why do we want to use the signOut() inside try/catch block?  If it is for logging purpose, wow about we add logging somewhere else?

Comment: @Franva There is a bug in NextJS 13.4 that throws an error in redirect. This is not how the signOut function is designed; it is only that there is a bug. Therefore, not using try/catch or handling the redirect error as you did are temporary workarounds - while the bug is being fixed in the following NextJS versions. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76510524/9982935

Comment: wow, interestingly Next.js put the throw error in their code. Good to know that :)