# Next.js 14 Redirect from Route.ts file

Tags: redirect, next.js

I'm trying to redirect from a route.ts file.

I'm using the following for the redirect:

```
return NextResponse.redirect(`http://localhost:3000/result`); // we need to redirect to a success page
```

Which kind of works it goes to the new page but then I get the error in the full-screen.

[image]

Error:

```
TypeError: Invalid URL

/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:140:13) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL',
  input: 'null',
  page: '/result'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out on this answer: [Next 13.4 Error: NEXT_REDIRECT in API routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76191324/next-13-4-error-next-redirect-in-api-routes) from Rugile Venskute

That there is a bug in the Route.ts where you can't do redirects within a try/catch block.

So here is my example code which works:

[image]

Comment: Could you supply this solution as text? Images are less useful, as they cannot be copied to the text clipboard.